# How to avoid being duplicated if the record is already deleted in mySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have following hypothetical table in mySQL.

```
Fields : EMP_ID (Primary ky), Employee_name (Unique), Emp_Age, Deleted (bit)
```

Employee_name is defined as unique. 
I will not physically delete records when delete is executed. Instead, I will update "Deleted" field to be 1. (not deleted=0). Now if I try inserting another record with the same employee name, the record will fail since its already there.

To avoid this situation, I could define a new "Index name" (Employee_Name and Deleted). But this will only work once. Second delete will fail since I can not now change "Deleted" field to 1 since its already there.

Is there a better way to handle this case?

I could add a third field like "Deleted_Date" and add that to the "Index name" (Employee_Name, Deleted, Deleted_Date) which will work (Since "Deleted_Date" will not be duplicated). But is it a good method?

Comment: You don't want to restore the 'deleted' row?

Comment: No once deleted, its deleted for ever. Need to insert if necessary later

Comment: I guess we can conclude that it doesn't make much sense for employee name to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You'll run into all sorts of problems with a unique index on employee name. Eventually you'll have 2 active employees with the same name. If you design incorporating this fact, you won't have the problem of duplicate if deleted.

Also, I like using at "status" instead of a Boolean/bit field. It allows you some flexibility when you have people that are on leave or inactive or whatever.